# I need help adding a second custom menu item to the WooCommerce account area menu

Tags: menus, account

I copied (and customised) the following code which I found online into my functions.php. It has allowed me to add an extra menu item to my WooCommernce account area menu. I now need to add a second menu item and I am not sure how to do this. Does anyone have any advice?

```
/*My account menu item*/
add_filter ( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'misha_one_more_link' );
function misha_one_more_link( $menu_links ){

    // we will hook "anyuniquetext123" later
    $new = array( 'anyuniquetext123' => 'Tour itineraries' );


    // array_slice() is good when you want to add an element between the other ones
    $menu_links = array_slice( $menu_links, 0, 2, true )
    + $new
    + array_slice( $menu_links, 2, NULL, true );


    return $menu_links;


}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_endpoint_url', 'misha_hook_endpoint', 10, 4 );
function misha_hook_endpoint( $url, $endpoint, $value, $permalink ){

    if( $endpoint === 'anyuniquetext123' ) {

        // ok, here is the place for your custom URL, it could be external
        $url = site_url('/tour-itineraries');

    }
    return $url;

}
```